# How I can confirm that scotch whisky consumed by me is a genuine high quality scotch Whisky Bought by INDIAN RUPEES

Tags: taste, recommendations, whiskey, scotch, champagne

My question is about the ALCOHOLIC BEVERAGES' taste?

HOW do tasters decide that the genuine quality of  Scotch whisky is of high quality by tasting.

AND

How do official testers determine   authenticity?

Comment: Scotch is made in Scotland, if it says scotch it is made in Scotland. - https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scotch_whisky#Labelling - https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scotch_whisky#Flavour_and_aroma

Comment: @AlaskaMan I don’t disagree, but counterfeit booze is, I believe, a billion dollar business. Thus articles like this: https://arstechnica.com/science/2020/09/its-now-possible-to-detect-counterfeit-whisky-without-opening-the-bottle/?amp=1

Comment: If someone isn't able to tell the difference in taste between the genuine article and a counterfeit, then, assuming it isn't actually toxic, why does it matter what quality it is. Let them enjoy the bargain price, or the excellent year, in ignorant bliss. ¶ More generally, think of how many people buy expensive wine even though they themselves can't tell the difference between it and the cheap stuff; a waste of money for them and a waste of good wine for those that *can* taste the difference.

Comment: If a party is arranged by a company to discuss business deals with another company. the discussion will not be successful because guests are not satisfied with it. the counterfeit booze. user-37920

Comment: It would be nice if the down-voters either posted a comment indicating *why* (or up-voted an existing comment that already gives that reason).  Simply down-voting without saying why isn't helpful, and for new users may be harmful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> HOW do tasters decide that the genuine quality of Scotch whisky is of high quality by tasting

It is an acquired skill developed over time with education and experience.

It is  learned from much education, a  long history of tasting and learning how to interpret what you are tasting by drawing on that education and experience.

> How do official testers determine authenticity?

I suggest you [take  a class](https://www.scotchwhiskyexperience.co.uk/training)  ([there are others](https://duckduckgo.com/?q=scotch%20tasting%20classes&t=ffsb&ia=web))or join a group of scotch lovers, (*create one if you cannot find one*) and try to attract other [Scotch connoisseur](https://duckduckgo.com/?t=ffcm&q=Scotch%20connoisseur&ia=web)'s in your area.

Educate yourself by doing much [research](https://thingsinindia.in/scotch-whisky-brands/), [reading](https://www.whiskiedwanderlust.com/guide-to-the-scotch-regions-of-scotland/) and **TASTING**.